# Basic Android app no icon on installation

Tags: android, xml, icons

I'm new to Android, and I'm trying to install the most basic application onto my phone to get started.

I followed the steps at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html and my app's icon does not appear in my phone's applications after installing. It appears in Settings > Applications > Manage Applications, but nowhere in my application list. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S2 i9100.

Here is my manifest. This was autogenerated by Eclipse.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Since you have not made your application as launcher application, so your application icon is not shown on the UI. also no Activity is registered in manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest is too short.
Your application isn't added to the launched applications list.
You have to add your application to the list by specifying following description in your Manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.YOUR_HOME_ACTIVITY"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
```

That's all.